# How many built in antenna does Raspberry Pi 4B has?

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I am doing a project, which requires my using multiple antenna to obtain the CSI using Raspberry Pi, but I only got one CSI stream all the time, I just wondering how many built in antenna does Raspberry Pi 4B has for the WIFI module?

Comment: `using multiple antenna to obtain the CSI`... What exactly do you mean by this? Can you give more details on what exactly you want / need to achieve? Please update your question with this information.

Comment: I mean using multiple antenna to form a MIMO system with my router, to capture Wi-Fi signal and extract channel statement information by using [Nexmon CSI tool](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon_csi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just one antenna, and AFAIK it is shared between WiFi and Bluetooth.